# Where I can get ejabberd full account JID in macOS setup?

Tags: ios, flutter, macos, homebrew, ejabberd

I have completed these steps :
[steps of ejabberd setup in macOs](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2FbS7.png)

Then i have opedn localhost server and it requies Username and password so which username and password i have to put becase as per previous image username and password are not working.
[localhost server and it requies Username and password](https://i.stack.imgur.com/4jbEs.png)

Iusername and password are not working. So how can i find these two perameters.

Answer (score 0):

In general, ejabberd installations have no account registered.

As you can see, step 3 in [Homebrew installation](https://docs.ejabberd.im/admin/installation/#homebrew) says:

> Create the account `admin@localhost` with password set as `password`:
> `/usr/local/sbin/ejabberdctl register admin localhost password`

In that case, the JID is `admin@localhost` and the password is `password`

Comment: its not working that's why I have posted this issue

Comment: "Its not working" is a problem description so precise that can only get a solution as precise as "Stop it and start again" :D